# What is the meaning of the different colored lines in Google Ngram?

Tags: google-ngram-viewer

I was searching for the word "chummy" in Google and went to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chummy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true). It showed me usage over a time period, but there were two lines, one red and one green. I could not figure out what those lines meant. I did not enter any additional criteria. In some of the corpora, it also showed third orange line which is understandable.
Can someone explain what these initial two lines mean?

[image: "chummy" case insensitive search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line are for different capitalizations of the word searched, in this case

- red: chummy
- green: Chummy
- orange: CHUMMY

This happens when the case in-sensitive checkbox is checked.

---

When I was trying to reproduce the screenshot, I first searched "chummy" in American English corpus just because I'm used to do that. I noted that there was only two lines, so I changed to British English, and noted that the orange line was not present, so I was wondering why this happen.

I think that the variations between American English and British English could be due to variations between the corpus of books being compared. Appears to me that CHUMMY doesn't have significant apparitions in American English but it does have it in British English.

**References**

- [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info)

Comment: Thanks.That answered my question,but how you concluded about word's usage in American and British English if lines showing analysis only for different capitalisation.

Comment: @Sofiko Now I realized that I added that as a note to self. I added an introductory paragraph to that note. I hope that it answers your comment.